# Plesk Umlauts in Paths not working

Tags: server, path, plesk, diacritics

after a server-migration of my Wordpress Website from an old shared server to a new AWS EC2 machine with Plesk running, everything worked fine. However the only problem I'm facing is that older image uploads (that worked totally fine on the old shared server) with "Umlauts" in the name are not working on the new machine.

e.g. **/uploads/2018/Würth-1.jpg**
*/uploads/2018/Wu%CC%88rth-1.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server*

As mentioned, it worked on the older server. In general I know that those character should be avoided and I mostly do, however in this case it's an older upload and still has it.

Is there a way to make a server-setting to make those work?

Comment: Is it Linux or Windows? Try to comment out `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');` and `define('DB_COLLATE', '');` to make WordPress to use server settings.

Comment: If that does not help, check out this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325761/.